# Can't resolve all parameters for MdlDialogReference

Tags: angular, material-design-lite, angular2-mdl

I am trying to use `angular2-mdl` component and to display a dialog. Only when I need to use `MdlDialogReference` do I get this error. I can create the dialog provided I try not to inject `MdlDialogReference`.

I have seen other answers to somthing like this but I cannot seem to transfer that into my solution. What needs to be done to get this to not fail?

Some files: Using angular 2.4.1

**package.json**

```
... 
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "3.4.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.4.1",
    "angular2-mdl": "^2.13.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "material-design-lite": "1.3.0",
...
```

**system.config.js**

```
(function (global) {
    System.config({
        paths: {
            // paths serve as alias
            'npm:': 'node_modules/'
        },
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things
        map: {
            // our app is within the app folder
            app: 'app',
            // angular bundles
            '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
            '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
            '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
            '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
            '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
            '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
            'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs',
            'angular2-mdl': 'npm:angular2-mdl'
        },
        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        packages: {
            app: {
                main: './main.js',
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            rxjs: {
                defaultExtension: 'js'
            },
            'angular2-mdl': {
                main: 'bundle/angular2-mdl.js'
            }
        }
    });
})(this);
```

**app.module.ts**

```
//angular
import { MdlModule, MdlDialogReference } from 'angular2-mdl';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

//routing
import { routing, appRoutingProviders } from './app.routing';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

//pages
...

//components
import { MessageDialogComponent } from './components/messageDialog.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        DateTimePickerModule,
        MdlModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        routing
    ],
    providers: [
        appRoutingProviders,
        MdlDialogReference,
        MessageDialogComponent,
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        MessageDialogComponent,
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [MessageDialogComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**messageDialog.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, HostListener, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { MdlDialogService, MdlDialogReference } from 'angular2-mdl';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'message-dialog',
    templateUrl: 'messageDialog.component.html'
})
export class MessageDialogComponent implements OnInit {


    constructor(@Inject(MdlDialogReference) private dialog: MdlDialogReference)
    { }

    public ngOnInit() {

    }

    @HostListener('keydown.esc')
    public onEsc(): void {
        this.dialog.hide();
    }
}
```

> Error: Can't resolve all parameters for MdlDialogReference: (?). at
>   SyntaxError.ZoneAwareError
>   (http://localhost:5111/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:992:33) at
>   SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor]
>   (http://localhost:5111/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1590:18)
>   at new SyntaxError
>   (http://localhost:5111/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:1793:18)
>   at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata
>   (http://localhost:5111/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18477:33)
>   at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata
>   (http://localhost:5111/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18352:28)
>   at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata
>   (http://localhost:5111/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18340:23)
>   at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata
>   (http://localhost:5111/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18582:42)
>   at eval
>   (http://localhost:5111/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18540:51)
>   at Array.forEach (native) at
>   CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata
>   (http://localhost:5111/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18507:21)
>   at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata
>   (http://localhost:5111/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:18191:52)
>   at JitCompiler._loadModules
>   (http://localhost:5111/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27288:66)
>   at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents
>   (http://localhost:5111/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27248:54)
>   at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync
>   (http://localhost:5111/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js:27214:23)
>   at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone
>   (http://localhost:5111/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:8496:29)

Comment: Not used this but Material2 dialog works perfectly https://material.angular.io/components/component/dialog and is easy to setup.

Comment: how did you use the MessageDialogComponent? can't see any dialogService.showCustomDialog call. also you don't need to add   MdlDialogReference and MessageDialogComponent to your providers array. did you check this example: http://mseemann.io/angular2-mdl/dialogs and the wiki: https://github.com/mseemann/angular2-mdl/wiki/How-to-use-the-MdlDialogService#custom-dialog

Comment: The `MdlDialogReference` by the looks is needed to do `this.dialog.hide();`

Comment: @michael. I did follow that guide. I was able to bring up the dialog no issues, however referencing `MdlDialogReference` causes this issue. If I can get away not using it that would be great. But I need a way to easily close the dialog

Comment: @aqwert sure, but i can't see a call like dialogService.showCustomDialog. how did you open the dialog? The MdlDialogReference-Instance is only created if you open the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

You're not able to use MdlDialogReference till a dialog is opened, so you can access it through the observable returned from showCustomDialog like this

```
this.dialogService.showCustomDialog({
  component: CustomDialogComponent, 
  providers: [{ provide: "data", useValue: data }],     
  isModal: true,
  clickOutsideToClose: true
}).subscribe( (ref: MdlDialogReference) => {
  ref.onHide().subscribe(() => {
    this.foo();
  })
});
```